# Google API Oauth2 timing out on the live site

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I have made an implementation for accessing the YouTube and Analytics APIs, which on localhost works fine, but when I try it in pre-production the request just times out and the consent window for authentication never even shows up.

This is my YouTube authentication code:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,  // view and manage your YouTube account
                                 YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl,
                                 YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner,
                                 YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubepartnerChannelAudit,
                                 YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly,
                                 YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload};

try
{
    // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
    UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                                    new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                    , scopes
                                    , userName
                                    , CancellationToken.None
                                    , new DatabaseDataStore("Youtube")).Result;

    YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(new YouTubeService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Masterpiece",
    });
    return service;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
    return null;

}
```

I basically have a "Connect" button on the page and when I click it the page should do a postback and authenticate to the Google API on the server-side. But on pre-production the postback just hangs and eventually I get this error message:
[image]

Comment: what type of client is it?

Comment: It's the .NET client. I'm using this in a WebForms project.

Comment: I meant what type of Client id?  Client ID for web application  I assume? did you remember to change the redirect uri to the pre production server?

Comment: It's a Client ID for web application. I have both redirect URIs set up for this credential in the Google Developers Console, and authorized JS origins.

Comment: Make sure there aren't any firewalls/proxies blocking requests to the API.